# Profiling Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling

I have a working app that have startup delays. I would  like to profile to see which method/API calls takes most of the delay time. Does Android studio or anything else offer such functionality? I will appreciate a link to documentation, tutorial or video on the same,

Comment: You can check [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler/?gclid=CjwKCAjwxev3BRBBEiwAiB_PWD47ZwrwjL_ysjB0Mk0xpB9s1qhIMZv7NM5ti7GDWLcbt8wQemj8qBoCl34QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: I have read again but the docs falls short on describing after-profile reading/analysis. After running the profiler, I don't see anywhere  describing how to make sense of it

Comment: Am especially interested in method calls and how long they took to execute

Comment: Well in that case check [this](https://proandroiddev.com/measuring-execution-times-in-kotlin-460a0285e5ea)

Comment: That's quiet helpful, except that the code involves libraries that Gradle installs